# What are ThreadPoolExecutors jobs in web UI's Spark Jobs?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark SQL 1.6.1 and am performing a few joins.

Looking at the spark UI I see that there are some jobs with description "run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142"

[image: Example of some of these jobs]

I was wondering why do some Spark jobs get that description?

Comment: this has been fixed in spark 3.x where we see `broadcast exchange (runId 299b13c3-e4cf-4b3f-903f-44497bf192d7)
$anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$1 at FutureTask.java:266` now

Answer (score 44, accepted):

After some investigation I found out that **run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142** Spark jobs are related to queries with `join` operators that fit the definition of `BroadcastHashJoin` where one join side is broadcast to executors for join.

That `BroadcastHashJoin` operator uses a `ThreadPool` for this asynchronous broadcasting (see [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/joins/BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala#L67) and [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/exchange/BroadcastExchangeExec.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L66)).

```
scala> spark.version
res16: String = 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT

scala> val left = spark.range(1)
left: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [id: bigint]

scala> val right = spark.range(1)
right: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [id: bigint]

scala> left.join(right, Seq("id")).show
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
+---+
```

When you switch to the SQL tab you should see **Completed Queries** section and their **Jobs** (on the right).

[image: SQL tab in web UI with Completed Queries]

In my case the Spark job(s) running on "run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142" where ids 12 and 16.

[image: Jobs tab in web UI with "run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142" jobs]

They both correspond to `join` queries.

If you wonder "that makes sense that one of my joins is causing this job to appear but as far as I know join is a shuffle transformation and not an action, so why is the job described with the ThreadPoolExecutor and not with my action (as is the case with the rest of my jobs)?", then my answer is usually along the lines:

Spark SQL is an extension of Spark with its own abstractions (`Dataset`s to name just the one that quickly springs to mind) that have their own operators for execution. One "simple" SQL operation can run one or more Spark jobs. It's at the discretion of Spark SQL's execution engine how many Spark jobs to run or submit (but they do use RDDs under the covers) -- you don't have to know such a low-leve details as it's...well...too low-level...given you are so high-level by using Spark SQL's SQL or Query DSL.

Comment: Dr. Laskowski to the rescue

Comment: bhot hard bhot hard. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when reading and writing to csv.

During those operations is when I first witnessed this threadpoolexecutor for the first time.