# Spark run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145 - What does it do

Tags: apache-spark, threadpoolexecutor

Experts,
I am running a spark job and could find lot of tasks with 
run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145

Env - Linux
Version - 1.6
Java - 1.7

What does this do and why there are lot running during execution ?
Any pointers on how to investigate will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: It appears that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852622/what-are-threadpoolexecutors-jobs-in-web-uis-spark-jobs may answer your question.