# spark iterative programming - exit condition without launching a job

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When writing iterative programs, a common situation is that you need to define a condition at which the program will stop execution and return the result. This stop condition can be for example rdd.isEmpty. The problem is that this "condition test" is an action which triggers a job to be executed and therefore schedueling,serialisation and others costs for each iteration

```
 def iterate(layer:RDD[Long])={

 layer.cache()

 if(layer.isEmpty) return null;


 val nextlayer=process(layer)//contains hashjoins, joins, filters, cache

 iterate(nextlayer)
 }
```

The timeline will look like:

[isempty][------spacing----][isempty][------spacing----][isempty]

what is the best way for iterative programming in such situtation? we should not be forced to launch a job in each iteration.

is there a method to check for empty rdd without executing an action?

possible solution:

as you can see in the image below, the is empty is now executed every 5 iterations.each iteration is represented by a periodic triplets of blue rectangles. i did this by modifying the stop condition to the following:

```
if(layer.index%5==0 && layer.isEmpty) return null;
```

But as you can see in the figure below am still getting actions that get executed as "run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java". A research shows that those actions are happenning because i am doing "broadcast hash joins" of small DFs with larger ones

[threadpoolexecutor reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852622/what-are-threadpoolexecutors-jobs-in-web-uis-spark-jobs)

[timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCAaj.png)

Comment: This is not correct: is there a method to check for empty rdd without executing an action

Comment: If you don't execute the job there is no possible way to know if an `RDD` is empty or not. If your transformations on that `RDD` can be statically reduced to `rdd.filter(_ => false)`, then it would _theoretically_ be possible, but then your code would probably not be doing anything useful.

Comment: I agree. i am trying to find a way to implement conditional iterative programming wihout trigering several jobs. trigering jobs is killing the performance gain we got by using an in memory computation.

Comment: i added an edit, showing that i am able to reduce the "isempty" calls. but i am still getting "run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java".

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
layer.cache()      
layer.isEmpty
```

This means that the check for `empty` is going to trigger an action, but the `rdd` will be cached, so when you pass it to the `process` method, the things that were done in `isEmpty` will be "skipped".

Comment: thanks, i am doing this already. i updated my descritpion. the problem is with laucnhing jobs on each iteration. launching jobs is killing the performance.